# How prevent the transition to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I have two activities. One activity is the authorization activity and the other navigation drawer with fragments. When I walk the way of registration and get on the navigation, I should not get to the login activity using the system back button.

How can I block this transition, if my system buttons busy:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: He is looking to **exactly** do the opposite :) You can call `finish()` in the authorization activity and it'll get destroyed, then pressing back will exit the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you don't want your application coming back to login activity you should finish it after starting your navigation activity.

```
void onAuthorized() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginActivity` xml description in manifest, add:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Like @Alex mentioned in the comments below, this flag will NOT work if you're using `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Be cautious with this flag. If your login activity calls some other activities for result this flag will break it

Comment: Of course. Anyway, I'll add this info in the edit. Thanks!